# Is it possible to put HTML inside TeX/MathML with MathJax the way it can be done with jqMath?

Tags: html, mathjax, mathml, jqmath

Using jqMath you can use **\html** to insert html inside mathematical expressions, such as in

```
\[y = ax^\html'&lt;input type="text" size=1>'+bx+c\]
```

This results in the following expression displayed to the user with a html input before the first +

*y=ax[actual input here]+bx+c*

So.. is it possible to achieve the same using MathJax?

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/mathjax-users/browse_thread/thread/60ed8c30e898715a) on the MathJax user forums to be helpful.

Davide

Comment: `semantics` and `annotation` elements associate Content MathML with a presentation. The HTML 5 spec also allows HTML inside Presentation MathML token elements, such as `mtext`. Hope this helps.